# Redirect to new blog using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, client-side, blogs

I closed my old blog so I redirect our old blog to our new blog but if any user comes from the old blog then he can't watch our video in our blog..
i used

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function java() {
        window.location = "http://anirudhagupta.blogspot.com";
    }

</script>
```

But he redirect like a ajax so Silverlight video object is not worked so how can i solve it using jquery or javascript

Comment: Why don't you use *meta* redirect? Why break the back button?

Comment: EFraim  Thanks for sharing information with us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't do JS redirects.** This is the worst possible option. JS redirects are not reliable (what if the user has diasbled JS?), they break browser history behavior and they have much better *and correct* alternatives.

Prefereably, use one of these:

- Server-side HTTP redirect (code 301)
- `<meta>` redirect (such as: `<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.new-domain.com">`)

Answer (score 3):

you shoulnd't use javascript to redirect to your new blog. there are better ways to do this
(ie. [301 permanent redirect](http://www.google.it/search?q=301+redirect+from+blogspot&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)). anyway, the issue with videos is not related to the redirect.

Comment: +1 301 is by far the best option both for usability and for SEO (any ranking you have will migrate to the new URL). JavaScript and meta-refresh hacks are only for desperate situations where you can't do a proper redirect.

Answer (score 0):

just this should do the trick ( if you are using jQuery )

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     window.location.href="http://anirudhagupta.blogspot.com"
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is not an AJAX redirect (which really doesn't exist, anyway). That Javascript redirect works fine for me. I don't see any Flash on your page, but the Silverlight is working fine.

Comment: @Anirudha: No, nothing is fine. Using JS redirects is a criminal offense

Comment: criminal offense why. i am owner of this two blog and i have a right to use it. if you not know it then read Blogspot Privacy policy first.

Comment: @Anirudha... @EFraim is being sarcastic. He was simply saying the fact that it "works" doesn't mean it is the best solution, not that you were breaking the law.